# How to export Wordpress with complete settings?

Tags: wordpress

I know that wordpress can be exported in the form of XML, but there are minor changes that we need to do after importing it to another location. Is there any way to export wp with complete settings like theme, widgets and other settings etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump the MySQL database and just pull it back into the new MySQL server location.  However, depending on what changes you need plug-ins, etc. will still need installed at the file system.  I would transfer the entire MySQL database and then all the WordPress files, then make any necessary changes once it's moved over (of course modify the wp-config.php file for the new MySQL database settings on the new host).